# Unable to display the LaunchScreen Image in Swift spritekit app

Tags: ios, swift, launch-screen

I'm having the problem with LauchScreen in ios, I've prepared multiple images for the Launch Image Source. Also removed the text and the contents from the LaunchScreen.xib file so that the images will be displayed at runtime, yet, only black screen shows up. How am I supposed to prepare and set the image? I've searched similar questions but had no solutions that helped me. I would love to hear some tips and help from you!

Answer (score 0):

Sounds to me like the image referenced in the Launch Image Source has a file extension in all caps, such as "image.**PNG**" instead of "image.**png**". Just rename the file extension to the latter and everything should work well.